# Trade Capture Report - QuickFix

Tags: c#, quickfix

I am sending a Trade capture report request with 35 = AD.

I am getting an acknowledge message back with 35=AQ(TradeCaptureReportRequestAck) and then a series of 35=AE(TradeCaptureReport) messages but I only see them in the log file.

I am not getting any Message back  on my fromApp() method. I don’t know if this is the right method that I should be coding my logic for listening a call back from server.

Can you please help here, which callback method I need to implement so that I can listen to the trade capture sent by the server.

Thanks,
Arshya

Comment: crack(message, sessionID) in fromApp and then override OnMessage method to specifically handle TradeCaptureReportRequestAck and any other messages

Comment: yes that's what I have done :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes you use `fromApp()` after all what other choice is there? Output a debug log message for every message that goes through fromApp and check you see the messages in your debug log.

Comment: I will check that. BTW I am getting 35=3 after every 35=AE for some reason. Could this having anything to do with the problem?

Comment: @Arshya - Yes it is a reject message.Check what is the entry in field 373. Should tell you the reason for all your problems.

Comment: It says required tag missing. But I have all the tags and I am getting  35=AE and correct trades but after every AE I get 35=3

Comment: @Arshya - Did you check your FIX XML config file and confirmed if the required fields are present ? How did you confirm if all tags are present ? If the tag is missing, then your message isn't complete.

Comment: Yeah I just figured out the issue. The XML is faulty. I still don't have it working but its definitely the xml. I am working on that right now.